# how to make a bat file on usb?

Tags: usb, batch-file, drive-letter

I want to make a batch file that open multiple programs like setuping drivers 
like this one

```
cd\
D:    (the usb drive letter )
start sound driver.exe
start  tochpad driver.exe
```

Just from opening the batch file from the hard drive of the computer not the USB pendrive.

And the problem is the usb changes its drive  letter on every single computer .. guys any help here please ?

[image]

Comment: the programs that i want to run is in the usb not the hard drive

Comment: Why not put the batch on the pen drive?

Comment: because i want to start it from the hard drive

Comment: Yes but what's the actual reason for that? Why would you have that batch on the hard drive (how does it get there?) but not the corresponding driver files? Did the loop method help you out?

Comment: no it did not help me because i did not know how to use it ...it worked and showed me the usb drive letter but how can i use it .... the one that worked with me is this  ------
@echo off
for /F "tokens=1*" %%a in ('fsutil fsinfo drives') do (
   for %%c in (%%b) do (
      for /F "tokens=3" %%d in ('fsutil fsinfo drivetype %%c') do (
         if %%d equ Removable (
            echo Drive %%c is Removable (USB^)
         )
      )
   )
)

Comment: Don't post code in comments. ;) Figure out what displays the drive letter and work from there. That's where you want your code to go.

Comment: i tried but did not know how to use the appeared drive letter ... please help

Comment: So you don't have any clue what you're actually doing? Just replace the `D:` in your example by `%%c`.

Comment: so it will be like @echo off
for /F "tokens=1*" %%a in ('fsutil fsinfo drives') do (
   for %%c in (%%b) do (
      for /F "tokens=3" %%d in ('fsutil fsinfo drivetype %%c') do (
         if %%d equ Removable (
            echo Drive %%c is Removable (USB^)
         )
      )
   )
)

cd\
%%c:    
start sound driver.exe
start  tochpad driver.exe

Comment: because it did not work with me   http://postimg.org/image/6uekcro3p/

Comment: Don't post code in the comments. Your code is wrong. The %%c doesn't have a : at the end and is the the wrong location. It needs to be in the loop not behind it. Look at the formatting in my answer and put it on the same level as the echo.

Comment: DID NOT WORK also  http://postimg.org/image/tkcqfpx0l/

Comment: the first one did not show anything

Comment: THANK YOU I FOUND THE PROBLEM  MY DRIVE LETTER WAS NOT IN THIS (D: E: F: G: H: I: etc...) SO I ADDED it

Comment: Nice that it helped. Alternatively you could use `cd /D %%c` which also should work with the `fsutil` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put some kind of identification file on the drive and iterate the drives. If you find said file you know you found the pendrive. This will stop working if said file is not present.

An example for this would be: [Detect USB and copy *.* to USB drive using batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10868613/detect-usb-and-copy-to-usb-drive-using-batch-script)

According to that the easy way would be the following assuming a file called "USB.txt":

```
@echo off
for %%d in (D: E: F: G: H: I: etc...) do (
   if exist %%d\USB.txt (
      echo USB at drive %%d connected
      %%d
      start sound driver.exe
      start tochpad driver.exe
   )
)
```

For a better solution(s) check the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10868613/detect-usb-and-copy-to-usb-drive-using-batch-script) I linked. The above already has several pitfalls as someone might use A: and B: as normal drive letters or the USB.txt might not be present.

If you look at the "corrected" solution from that question it would be:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=1*" %%a in ('fsutil fsinfo drives') do (
   for %%c in (%%b) do (
      for /F "tokens=3" %%d in ('fsutil fsinfo drivetype %%c') do (
         if %%d equ Removable (
            echo Drive %%c is Removable (USB^)
            %%c
            start sound driver.exe
            start tochpad driver.exe
         )
      )
   )
)
```

From what I can tell `fsutil` needs to be executed with admin priviliges so you will have to watch out for that depending on what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that, when clicking on (running) the bat file from explorer, the current directory is set to the location of the batch file.

So if your batch file is stored and run from a directory on the USB stick, then you are already in a directory that has that drive letter. You do not need to switch drives, so you do not need to specify it.

So just use `CD \` which will ensure you are at the root level of the drive you are on.

You do not need to use a drive letter to access other directories on the same drive either. If you are in the folder `c:\temp`:

`123\file.txt` is equivalent to `c:\temp\123\file.txt` (no leading slash, so the path is added to the current path)

`\123\file.txt` is equivalent to `c:\123\file.txt` (leading slash, so the path is added to the drive letter only (called the "root")

This can get a little complicated if you are starting other batch files from within the batch file that also need to know which directory they are in. I don't think you are in this situation based on your example.

see also ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255184/ ) for more in-depth discussion regarding how to find the current working directory.

Comment: note also that in your example, you would change to the correct drive *first*, and then change to your desired directory using `cd`. In your example, It would have worked anyway but if you had `cd \temp` and then `d:` you would **not** have been in `d:\temp`

Comment: bro i know all what you typed .. what i want to do is start the batch file from a partition of the pc to open a program in the usb.. and i need to make the batch file auto find the usb drive letter and use it because it changes every time

Comment: For batches you could also consider using [`~dp0`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034076/what-does-dp0-mean-and-how-does-it-work) by using `cd /D` it would ensure the drive change.

Comment: this the bat file 

start sound driver.exe
 
start tochpad driver.exe 
.....can any one edit it for me because i did not understood the method NB. these files are in the usb